# Taylor series expansion of function $4^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I want to expand a function to a Taylor series.
The function:
$$y=4^{x^2}$$

I'm wondering if I can just get a series of $4^x$ and then just substitute $x$ by $x^2$ similarly to when we expand $\cos(x^2)$ we first expand $\cos(x)$ and then substitute $x^2$ in the resulting series.
Can we do the same in the case of my function? My intuition says no, but I can't actually explain why.

I followed my intuition and expanded the function without substitution.
I got this result:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4ln(2)^n(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot x^{2n}$$
This result differs from the result that I could get using substitution.
So I either made a mistake or substitution is not allowed here. What is the case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$ 4^{x^2}=\exp\left(2x^2\log 2\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2\log 2)^n}{n!}x^{2n}.$$

Comment: When you differentiate a function with argument $x^2$, you get an additional $2x$ to multiply with, which you are losing in your method. In expansion of $cos x$, there are no extra terms for having $x^2$ in place of $x$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio you're right, replacing $log(4)=2log(2)$ is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is wrong. You can substitute $x$ by $x^2$. The reasoning is very simple:

If $$f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0}a_n x^n$$ **for all** $x$, then in particular it's valid for $x=y^2$, so $$f(y^2) = \sum_{n\ge 0}a_n y^{2n}$$
and then just rename the variable.

If you're interested in the radius of convergence you'll need to adjust it accordingly.